# How to draw text with image shape

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

[image]

I want to achieve text draw on image like this on react-native, I can draw text on circular image using [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg) but it doesn't fulfill my requirements.
Any other library or code that will be helpful to achieve desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this doesn't really answer the original question but you could just do it in photoshop? I think it would be far easier and far more customizable.

Comment: @no-display i want to achieve this on react-native app

Comment: You could then add the image you created on photoshop to react native. If you want the text to float you could just export the image as a png with the text around it. What you are trying to do is very complicated for something so simple and is set to bring problems down the road.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat - the `react-native-svg` you linked to appears to support that - this is from the readme: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/master/screenshots/text-path.png

Comment: @DonMag thanks for your comment. that is for line or a circle and I am looking the same for image.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat - so... are you looking for a way to analyze an image - figure out an "outline of part of the image" - and then curve text around it? That's going to take some work on your part... First step would be to start looking at image processing code that "finds edges."